# Unable to delete parent record in one to many relationship - Flask-SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask, one-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I've created to 3 simple model with flask-sqlalchemy with one to many relationship. Here is the code for models:

```
class UsersModel(BaseModel, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    info = db.relationship('UserInfoModel', backref="user", cascade="all, delete" , lazy='dynamic')
    notes = db.relationship('NotesModel', backref="owner", cascade="all, delete" , lazy='dynamic')

class UserInfoModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_info'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(55))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(55))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    profession = db.Column(db.String(255))

class NotesModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'notes'
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    desc = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

I can insert and retrive relational data without any problem but when I'm trying to delete a user it should also delete notes & info rather it gives error and don't let me delete. Here is the error that I see: http://prntscr.com/ek5cx1 
But if I delete notes & info and then try to delete user it works. It's doing the reverse. I tried using 'delete-orphan' but didn't worked. I have read the documentation and read some blog about it but nothing helps. Am I wrong about declaring the relation? If so please help me to implement this or help me to find error within my code.
Appriciate your help, Thanks

Update: After adding delete-orphan I can delete data from session but not form phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 2):

i think you want your relationships defined opposite how you have them, so like this:

```
       class UsersModel(BaseModel, UserMixin):
           __tablename__ = 'user'
          email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
          password = db.Column(db.String(255))
          confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())

       class UserInfoModel(db.Model):
           __tablename__ = 'user_info'
           id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
           user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
           first_name = db.Column(db.String(55))
           last_name = db.Column(db.String(55))
           age = db.Column(db.Integer)
           profession = db.Column(db.String(255))
           user = db.relationship('User',uselist=False, cascade='all, delete-orphan',backref=db.backref('info', uselist=False))

       class NotesModel(BaseModel):
           __tablename__ = 'notes'
           title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
           desc = db.Column(db.Text)
           user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
           user = db.relationship('User',uselist=False, cascade='all, delete-orphan',backref=db.backref('notes'.lazy='dynamic'))
```

Comment: yes BaseModel inherit from db.Model. BaseModel have some common fields...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've updated the question. Actually I think I've defined the relationship properly and it works when deleting using db session. But gives error when trying to delete from phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
cascade="all,delete"
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain your answer